# Sizes of UITextLabel inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel, textlabel

I have subclassed `UITableViewCell` by only overriding the `-(void)layoutSubviews` method:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];  //The default implementation of the layoutSubviews
    
    CGRect textLabelFrame = self.textLabel.frame;
    textLabelFrame.size.width = 180;
    self.textLabel.frame = textLabelFrame;
    self.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    self.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    
    CGRect detailTextLabelFrame = self.detailTextLabel.frame;
    detailTextLabelFrame.size.width = 30;
    self.detailTextLabel.frame = detailTextLabelFrame;
    self.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    self.detailTextLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    
    [self sizeToFit];

}
```

Inside the cell, I have also added a `UIStepper` subview in the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// code omitted   
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    if(indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:OrderCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if ( cell == nil ) {
            cell = [[GinkgoDeliveryOrderCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:OrderCellIdentifier];
            UIStepper * stepper = [[UIStepper alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(113, 7, 94, 29)];
            [cell addSubview:stepper];
        }
// code omitted
}
```

However, when the text for `textLabel` is too long, it seems to squeeze away the `detailTextLabel`. I am wondering why this is happening as I have already specify the frames for these subviews.
[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would suggest creating a custom Cell for this, instead of subclassing the currently available cell styles.

Comment: Is the text in label using the text property? (If so maybe change to  using the attributedText property and control the text behaviour with an NSAttributedString)

Comment: how is attributedText different from text? I am using text. @Bamsworld

Comment: That might work but what is wrong here? @Lefteris

Comment: Attributed strings give you a lot more control over the appearance of a string. However, looking at your code more in depth I'm curious as to the frames (origin and size) of textLabel and detailTextLabel @Ra1nWarden

Comment: @Bamsworld Thanks for the inspiration. I tried setting them manually and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As speculated in the comments [super layoutSubviews] is altering the frames of your labels and you are only changing the width.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have solved the problem by manually setting the `CGRect`for the frame:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];  //The default implementation of the layoutSubviews

    self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(15, 11, 180, 21);
    self.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    self.textLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

    CGRect detailTextLabelFrame = CGRectMake(280, 11, 40, 21);
    self.detailTextLabel.frame = detailTextLabelFrame;
    self.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    [self sizeToFit];

}
```

Thanks to @Bamsworld.